# SSL for single applicaiton on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, ssl, certificate

I have any ASP.Net application running on IIS 7.5.

How can I incorporate SSL certificate to an single application in a domain.

Example , I have a website as www.mywebsite.com. Now I created another application which can be accessed by typing  www.mywebsite.com/newapplication.

Now I could like to have SSL certificate only for www.mywebsite.com/newapplication and NOT FOR www.mywebsite.com.

IS THIS POSSIBLE ...???HOW  ??

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by configuring IIS to accept both http (80) and https (443) traffic. Then, configure your SSL certificate at site level. Now for each application that you create within your site (for example, your www.mywebsite.com/newapplication) you can explicitly configure if it requires SSL or not, by checking the **Require SSL** option under the **SSL settings**, visible in IIS management console when the application is selected.